# I wanna to show loop through array_keys but it gives me error says "array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given "

Tags: php, laravel

> array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

I tried to change the array keys to string but still it doesn't work

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::paginate(10);

    return view ('inventory.layout', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

And this is my view in Laravel:

```
@if (isset($products)) 

    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table col-xs table-striped">
    <!-- Return all the csv header as an array keys -->
    <thead>

    @if ($arrkeys = array_keys($products[0])) 

        @foreach ($arrkeys as $key)  
            <th>{{$key}}</th>
        @endforeach
    @endif 

@endif
```

Comment: Try `@if ($arrkeys = array_keys($products))` instead

Comment: Could you `dd($products);` so that we can see if there's a better way to access the data please? :)

Comment: Why not just use @foreach ($products as $key => $product) ? This way you can use $key to display the key value and $product to show the item value.

Answer (score 1):

The `paginate()` function will give you a collection not an array.
If you want to access it as an array, you should do this instead `$products = Product::paginate(10)->toArray();` hence will give you an array.
And to access the list of items, you can do this to check `dd($products['data'])` so as for your case it will be like this

```
    @if ($arrkeys = array_keys($products['data'][0])) 
        @foreach ($arrkeys as $key)  
            <th>{{$key}}</th>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Because the `$products` also contains other pagination informations, while the list of items are stored under `$products['data']`
Check `dd($products)` to see what other other pagination informations that I'm referring to.

Comment: Thanks Rio for helping. I've done like what said but it cames another poroblem says "Undefined index: data". I'm going to be mad of this... please help

Comment: could you update your post with the things that you've updated by following my answer? and what's the laravel version that you are using? Because I've been doing this paginate stuff a lot since laravel 5.5 until now 5.8 and the list of items were always in `$array['data']`. There also might be a chance the array structure for pagination is different for other laravel versions

Comment: but fastest way for you to check is try `dd($products)` and see the array structure, find the list of items is inside which array key

Comment: It show me this when i do dd($products); :- LengthAwarePaginator {#227 ▼
  #total: 30
  #lastPage: 10
  #items: Collection {#222 ▶}
  #perPage: 3
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost:8080/Import-CSV-Laravel/public/layout"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}

Comment: Please Rio let me know what is my problem, I even upgrated my Laravel from 5.5 to 5.6 but useless. Thanks in advance

Comment: that is a collection. Have you modified your line in your public function index? yours is `$products = Product::paginate(10);` it's supposed to be `$products = Product::paginate(10)->toArray();`

Comment: I found the problem, it's in table keys:  ($arrkeys= array_keys($products[0])) it says that it expected array but object given

Comment: the rest of code works with pagination very well, the error comms just from the array_ keys() function, what you think, what i'm suppose to do?

Comment: if you have done this `$products = Product::paginate(10)->toArray();` then the `$products` would already be an array. After it becomes an array, you can access the list of items by doing this `$products['data']`. So in your case you want to take the array keys of the first item and print it as a table header right? then it should be like this `@if ($arrkeys = array_keys($products['data'][0]))`. Have you followed all that?

Comment: Hurrah!, Thanks Rio for helping, finaly I fixed it, it's working great right now. The problem was in view, I converted the variable in array_keys() function from object to array. Like this: @if ($arrkeys= array_keys(($products[0])->toArray())).

Comment: great, happy to help. If my answer is correct, I'd really appreciate it if you could mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer for code above in view:

```
    @if ($arrkeys= array_keys(($products[0])->toArray()))

        @foreach ($arrkeys as $key)  
            <th>{{$key}}</th>
        @endforeach 

    @endif
```